# NetBeans Remote Access

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans

I know this has been asked before, but I'm really, really new to programming and honestly didn't understand any of the answers.
I'm trying to remotely connect to a server from NetBeans so I can debug a school project on my computer. I'm so lost on how to do it. I tried following some instructions using build host manager, but I didn't get how to make the remote ssh server show up. I'm on windows 7 and have been using cygwin and notepad++ without any trouble. Notepad++ just let me put the hostname, username, and password and it worked perfectly. Why is Netbeans more complicated than that? Do I need to install something else for it? I don't know what tomcat, glassfish, etc. any of those are because I need to chill out before I can take in any of the explanations.

Comment: What kind of project is it?

Comment: Does the kind of project really matter here?

Comment: @AB_ Yes it does. OP mentions tomcat and glassfish, as well as using a build host manager. It would help understand what OP is actually trying to do.

Comment: he wants to debug C++ application remotely using NetBeans

Comment: He mentioned tomcat and glassfish that are part of NetBeans because he doesn't understand wht needs to be done. Debugging, C++, NetBeans are 3 tags OP chosen

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about using NetBeans in GUI (you want to see NetBeans running on remote host) then you need to get a remote desktop: windows remote desktop or X11 VNC Server.

If you want to use NetBeans Remote Development feature, then all you need is NetBeans running on your localhost and access to the remote host via ssh protocol. It is described [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html).